# using d3, redraw the graph based on node click

Tags: json, d3.js, neo4j, cypher, graph-visualization

I am using a d3 force-directed graph that produces a hairball of data.  :-)
I think it's either this one: http://bl.ocks.org/1138500  or this one: http://bl.ocks.org/4062045 
(I inherited this so not exactly sure but these 2 visualizations are really similar!)

When I click a node, I'd like to zoom in on, or redraw the graph based on just that node.  So on click of a node, the other nodes and edges would disappear.  How can I do that?  I'm using Ruby on Rails and Neo4j, so a cypher query is creating the JSON data that d3 uses.

Will i have to re-query the database via cypher?  I hope not. I'm hoping that this can be done in d3.js alone.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.  If you have a working example, I'd love to see it!

Comment: should be possible in d3 alone, no need to requery, you might want to scan http://maxdemarzi.com for a suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to ask on the D3 mailing list.

Comment: Hi Peter.  Do you mean the google group?  I just asked it there.  Thanks.